# Can I create Java-classes from C/C++ only?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have heard about JNI and have tried to use it. What I would want to do is create a Java-class from C or C++ **only**, i.e. no Java code like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static { System.loadLibrary("myclass_impl.dll") }
    native public int someFunction(String string);
}
```

For example, Python allows to create *Extension Classes* from C whereby you could also wrap C-functions from a DLL using ctypes.

Is there a way to do this for Java?

Comment: Am I to understand you want to access functions that are written in C\C++ and have been compiled directly from your Java code? Short of writing them into your Java VM, I don't see that happening. That, btw, is roughly what Python does as well. 
So, possible? Yes. Practical? No, else people would not have written Java code like your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly not.  Java classes must be expressed in Java bytecode, which C and C++ are not (normally) equipped to generate.  Additionally, the Java memory model is substantially different from the model in C and C++, and requires its own unusual layout constraints and the like.

Unless you want to be implementing basically an entire Java compiler in C++, I would be surprised if this could be done.

Comment: +1: I would be surprised if it couldn't be done, but I would be equally surprised if someone came up with a good reason to do so.  You can just call `javac` from a C++ program.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: You can't call `javac`, as a command, from C++ program, because it is not part of JRE (remember, JDK is not supposed to be needed at runtime), but the actual compiler class should be and should therefore be callable via JNI.

Comment: @JanHudec normally you don't need the JDK but normally you don't need to decompile a class in which case it make sense to use the tool designed to do this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Compile, not _decompile_. I remember Eclipse is able to compile _without_ having JDK installed on the computer. It can also create Ant build script to build Java without JDK. It used some bits from Eclipse, but the base seems to be javax.tools.JavaCompiler.

Comment: @JanHudec that is because it has its own compiler which is like a cut down JDK. You wouldn't need a JDK if you had your own version.